# crontab does not execute script but it executable manually

Tags: cron

Want to schedule a sh-script but crontab does not execute it.
However, the script is executable manually without any issues.

"crontab -l"-Output:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
48 16 * * 1,2,3,4,5 /home/pentaho_admin/pdi/schedule.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

the shell script included a command with the following command in the 2nd line:
./kitchen.sh

1st line:
alias xyz="cd..." (leads to the folder of kitchen.sh)

That first line apparently cannot be interpreted by crontab.
Solution:
I've added the full path to kitchen.sh

Is there any more sexy solution?